# Status is payment after trying the Programmatically creating new order in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, contact-form-7

I am having the hardest time programmatically creating orders in WooCommerce.
We have a form on our website that wants the user to fill the **form and submit** it and create the order using the user details that he submitted in the form. here you can see the form https://www.fitnessoneformulas.com/select-a-free-product/

I have **two just** problems right now

1. we have a **dropdown of the products** in our form there he can select the product but we can't configure how we can call the **id of the selected product**.
2. We have to add the default id in our code to check if it's creating the order or not? and it's working very smoothly and creating the order but they **show me the status of the order is payment pending**.

NOTE: The price of all the products is Zero.

Here is the code that we have used to create the order

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'CF7_pre_send' );

function CF7_pre_send($cf7) {
    
    global $woocommerce;
    global $product;

    
  $address = array(
    "first_name" => $_POST["firstname"],
    "last_name" => $_POST["LastName"],
    "product" => $_POST["products-54"],
    "country" => $_POST["country_auto-565"],
    "state" => $_POST["state_auto-625"],    
    "city" => $_POST["city_auto-896"],
    "postcode" => $_POST["number-594"], 
    "address_1" => $_POST["Address"],
      "address_2" => $_POST["Address"],
    "phone" => $_POST["phonetext-523"],
    "email" => $_POST["email-557"]
      
  );

    
    file_put_contents("new_array.txt", $address);

   // Now we create the order
   $order = wc_create_order();

   // The add_product() function below is located in /plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract_wc_order.php
   $order->add_product( wc_get_product( '20604'), 1); // This is an existing SIMPLE product
   $order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
    $order->set_address( $address, 'shipping' );
   //
   $order->calculate_totals();
   $order->update_status("Completed", 'Imported order', TRUE); 
}
```

Only the order will create on the free product or the price is zero
Any help on this would be MOST appreciated!

Comment: be aware that wpcf7_before_send_mail is not sanitized user input.

Comment: so what is a good idea? let me know if you have

Answer (score 0):

```
$order->update_status("completed", 'Imported order', TRUE);
```

Order status should be in lower case like `completed` `on-hold`, `processing` `pending`, `cancelled`, `refunded`, `failed`

Comment: when I change it lower case it shows errors